# divide string in into equal parts

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, divide

I can sum up strings:

`result=[firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];`

I can subtract one string from another:

`result=[firstString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:secondString withString:@""];`

Can you help me to divide a string into equal strings (e.g. i have string @"Qwerty",  i want to divide it by 3 and get array @[@"Qw",@"er",@"ty"], or divide it by 2 to get @[@"Qwe",@"rty"])? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by devide a string into some equal strings? Can you give some example?

Comment: give an example string....

Comment: I assume he means something like `[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];`

Comment: You want N number of substrings with equal length? What would you do if the length is not divisible by N?

Comment: how would you split a word with odd length?

Comment: @peko even/odd is not the issue. For example: 9 is odd but divisible by 3. However 10 is even but not divisible by 3.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist right. i mean what if the word isn't divisible by 3?

Comment: if(string.length/3==(int)string.length/3){//divisible, to be divided}else{//not divisible}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the string length divide it by desired number and base of it create NSRange:

```
    NSString *str = @"Qwerty";
    int len = str.length;
    int devider = 2; // Change it to control result length

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += devider)
    {
        // You should do some validation to make sure your location and length is in range f string length
        NSRange ran = NSMakeRange(i, devider);
        NSString *res = [str substringWithRange:ran];
        NSLog(@"res: %@", res);
    }
```

You can create NSString category to achieve the result you are asking for.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! The simplest answer! +1.

Answer (score 1):

Please use function `[NSString substringWithRange:]`. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Yes David, Hearing You...!!!

Bellow is the code.

```
for(int i=0;i<strToDivide.length-iLengthToDivide;i=i+iLengthToDivide)
{
NSString *strPart=[strToDivide substringWithRange:(i,iLengthToDivide)];

[arrToStoreParts addObject:strPart];

//if the length of string is not perfectly divisible by iLengthToDivide
  if(i+iLengthToDivide>strToDivide.length)
 {
 strPart=[strToDivide substringWithRange:(i,strToDivide.length-i)];
 [arrToStoreParts addObject:strPart];
 }
strPart=nil;
}
}
```

arrToStoreParts will contain all strings came in resultset.

I thought bundling this function in a for loop is pretty easy and he would be able to do that as he is aware of other string functions so didn't give code initially. Hope it helps though :)

Comment: I think the OP would be more interested in *how* to calculate those ranges

Comment: Okay..Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray* array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int divide_factor = <your divide_factor>;

while (yourString.length) {

    NSString* substring = [yourString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(divide_factor, yourString.length))];

    [array1 addObject:substring];

    yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(divide_factor, yourString.length)) withString:@""];

}
```

The advantage is that, irrespective of the length of string, it does not throw any exceptions. The last substring will be the leftover substring after division.

TEST CASES:

(1)

```
yourString = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

divide_factor = 3;
```

Then results is:
(
    abc,
    def,
    ghi,
    jkl,
    mno,
    pqr,
    stu,
    vwx,
    yz
)

(2)

```
yourString = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

divide_factor = 7;
```

result:
(
    abcdefg,
    hijklmn,
    opqrstu,
    vwxyz
)

Comment: i would like not to get array with strings of N length, but to get N equal strings. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then all you got to do is determine your divide_factor.
Suppose you want it in 7 parts, then divide_factor become yourString.lengh/7. The only case you have to think about is improper fraction. In that case, the best you can do is discard the last substring.